# Unexpected output while calling method

Tags: java

```
public class Sandbox {

    private static int arg;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
           doSomething(i);
    }

    public static void doSomething(int arg) {
        if(arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3) doSomething(--arg);
        if(arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3) System.out.println(arg);
        Sandbox.arg = arg;
    }

}
```

The output when ran is as follows:

```
1
2
1
```

I expected this to output nothing, why does it output 1, 2 & 3?

Comment: Just debug that thing ..

Comment: Does it output 1,2,3 or 1,2,1?

Comment: The best way to find the answer to this kind of question is to step through it with a debugger, looking at all the relevant variables as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, eliminate your warty `Sandbox.arg`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 99; i > 0; i--)
        doSomething(i);
}

public static void doSomething(int arg) {
    if (arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3)
        doSomething(--arg);
    if (arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3)
        System.out.println(arg);
    // Sandbox.arg = arg;
}
```

and you still get

```
1
2
1
```

You're calling it with every value from 99,1 inclusive. That includes 3,2 and 1.

When called with a `3`,

```
if(arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3) doSomething(--arg); //<-- recurse with "2"
if(arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3) System.out.println(arg); //<-- print "2"
```

obviously when called with a `2`

```
if(arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3) doSomething(--arg); //<-- recurse with "1"
if(arg == 1) // <-- print "1".
```

So, you get `1` for the recursive call of 2 when arg is `3` then a 2 (because you predecremented arg). Then you get another `1` for the `2` in the loop from `main()`. Obviously on `1` the first `if` makes `arg` 0.

Comment: Did you notice my if statement?

Comment: @ChrisGray I edited my answer to try and clarify, but I did indeed see both of your `if` statements. Now consider (as I did) when `arg` is 3.

Comment: Shouldn't the if statement be called when I decrement and call the method?

Comment: It is called. But you don't `return doSomething(--arg);` so it continues to the next statement *after* it recurses.

Answer (score 0):

For the values of i from 99 to 4, the condition `if (arg == 1 || arg == 2 || arg == 3)` holds false and therefore no action takes place. However for `i=3, i=2, i=1` the condition is true.

Now, for i=3, the same frunction `doSomething(--arg);` is called recursively with arg as `--arg`, i.e. 2. Similarly it is called for i=1.

As the recursive function is called the current variable instances are stored in the stack.
Once the recursive call for i=1 is placed, the next statement `System.out.println(arg);` is called and it prints 1. Now the stack values are popped and the same statement executes for i=2 and similarly for i=3.